# Understanding profilehooks output, what does {min} mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling

The code is:

```
def slide_merge_forloop(rc1u,rc2wr):
    ret1 = []
    rc1ulen = len(rc1u)
    rc2wrlen = len(rc2wr)

    for i in xrange(min (rc1ulen, rc2wrlen)):
        if rc1u[i] == rc2wr[i]:
            ret1.append(rc1u[i])
        elif rc1u[i] == 'N':
            ret1.append(rc1u[i])
        elif rc2wr[i] == 'N':
            ret1.append(rc2wr[i])
        else:
            break
    return ret1
```

Below is the output from profiling this function as part of the main code, gained whilst using profilehooks as the profiling tool:

```
*** PROFILER RESULTS ***
slide_merge_forloop (Early_matcher.py:73)
function called 224794 times

         1181922 function calls in 1.004 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time, internal time, call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   224794    0.817    0.000    0.980    0.000 Early_matcher.py:73(slide_merge_forloop)
   224794    0.097    0.000    0.097    0.000 {min}
   449588    0.052    0.000    0.052    0.000 {len}
   224794    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    57952    0.014    0.000    0.014    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

Obviously I wish to speed up the code but the part I have issue with is what does the  {min} part mean? I dont call such thing at all during this part of my code and yet it is taking up a significant amount of time. I have the same issue with the "method 'disable' " section as I do not understand what that is either.

Any help in understanding this output would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this type of question should be places in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Isnt that for if you want help optimising your code? I dont want peoples help with that, I just need to understand what profilehooks means by these statements and figured if I put my code up then people can state "this line does this therefore the statmeent refers to this process".

Comment: "Obviously I wish to speed up the code" [*This works better.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)

Comment: Thanks for that, makes sense to identify which section likely takes up the time identified and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

It means the time spent executing the [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) built-in function